# WPF : Acceder los estilos de un Resource.xaml de una dll

Tags: c#, wpf

Hice una Dll para compartir estilos entre proyectos WPF y la puedo acceder desde las vistas XAML, pero ahora necesito acceder los estilos desde C#.

En C# hago este codigo :

```
*var rd = new ResourceDictionary();  
rd.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/POS_StylesSharing;Resources.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);*
```

Pero solo me muestra el siguiente error:

> System.IO.IOException: 'No se encuentra el recurso
>   'pos_stylessharing;resources.xaml'.'
>
> - La dll tiene los siguientes XmlnsDefinitionAttribute:    ("http://POS_Styles.com/POS/resources",
>     "POS_StylesSharing.Resources")
> - El namespace es: POS_StylesSharing.Resources
> - El nombre del Dll es: POS_StylesSharing
> - Los estilos los tengo en : /Styles/Resources.xaml

Ya intente completando

```
,,,/POS_StylesSharing**.dll** y/o **/Style/**Resources.xaml
```

pero sigue marcando el mismo error.

les agradezco si me dan una pista de lo que debo corregir.

Answer (score 1):

Ya localice mi falla y ya tengo mis estilos en C#
Antes:

```
rd.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/POS_StylesSharing;Resources.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Ahora:

```
rd.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/POS_StylesSharing;**component/Styles/**Resources.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
```

le faltaba la palabra '`component`' y la ruta física del `resource`. .